# Jar execution on startup at windows doesn't work, no result

Tags: java, windows, regedit

I added a key for the execution of a jar using the class that i found in an answer of Boann: [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)  . I'm working in a virtual box virtualized windows 7.

If I add in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" a notepad.exe value, it starts at startup.

I wrote in this key the value, and the keyname JAVALL

```
javaw -Xmx200m -jar
```

The entire code is:

```
if (Utilities.WindowsRegistry.isAvailable()) {+
            Utilities.WindowsRegistry.writeValue(
                    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", 
                    "JAVALL", 
                    "\"java.exe -jar "+ super.installPathFile + "\" ");
        }
```

Where super.installPathFile is similar at c:\users\kk\desktop\program.jar

But when I try to do the same in a jar in the desktop it doesn't start. I don't know where the error is!

Also another strange problem that I have when I go to the path in the regedit, the keynames and values are different that if I get its using the readValues() function. 
For example, I added the notepad in the key and it starts correctly, also i can see it in readValues() function. But when I go to the regedit I don't see the same keys that in the function! I'm working in a virtualized windows 7

Comment: what did you write in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\, please edit question...

Comment: Edited. What could be?

Comment: Please show exactly what you have in the JAVALL key (use regEdit to view, copy and past..). I would try with full path to the java virtual machine es."c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.31\bin\java.exe" -jar c:\users\kk\desktop\program.jar

Comment: That is another problem that I don't understand... When I go to the path in the regedit, the keynames and values are different that if I get it using the readValues() function. For example, I added the notepad in the key and it starts correctly, also i can see it in readValues() function. But when I go to the regedit I don't see the same keys that in the function! I'm working in a virtualized windows 7

Comment: For this I think you should open another question, with code you are using an example of what you get, an example of whats in regEdit.. ecc. For now what do you see in regEdit (windows) as a value of your JAVALL key

Comment: I can't found the JAVALL key in the regedit...

Comment: Ok I if i write the whole path to java.exe it works! :D You want to write the answer?

Comment: Yes, we need to close the question ; ), if it is working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted comment into answer:

Include **full path** to  java virtual machine es.

```
"c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.31\bin\java.exe" -jar c:\users\kk\desktop\program.jar
```